# React - Get text of div on click without refs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Is there an example where we can retrieve the value of a React element without the usage of refs? Is that possible?

```
var Test = React.createClass({

  handleClick: function() {
    alert(this.text);
  },
  render: function() {
    <div className="div1" onClick={this.handleClick}> HEkudsbdsu </div>
  }
})
```

Answer (score 48):

I found a working answer:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function(event) {
    alert(event.currentTarget.textContent);
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div className="div1" onClick={this.handleClick}> HEkudsbdsu </div>
  }
});
```

Comment: This did not work for me but @Ikram - Ud - Daula's answer did https://stackoverflow.com/a/50894853/5305519

Comment: Should be `event.target.textContent` the currentTarget is not exist in React API

Answer (score 6):

I suppose you can just get the DOM Node with `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);`, and then get its `innerText` or whatever you need from it.

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function() {
    var domNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
    alert(domNode.innerText);
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div className="div1" onClick={this.handleClick}> HEkudsbdsu </div>
  }
});
```

This is a bit of a runabout way of doing it, but it will work.

Note that pre 0.14 React, you'll just be using `React` and not `ReactDOM`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I get an undefined in the alert

Comment: @AshwinVenkataraman What version of React are you running? If it's the current version, then you need to import `ReactDOM` in your component.

Comment: I am running the latest version. I am using this link to import the script files: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js, and for React-dom - https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js

Comment: @AshwinVenkataraman What happens when you `console.log` out `domNode`? Is the node findable? Does it have text? Can you give any more information as to what is missing here?

Answer (score 4):

Try this way.

```
handleMenuItemClick = (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.textContent);
};

<option onClick={event => this.handleMenuItemClick(event)}>
  item
</option>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to retrieve text, use `innerText` property, if html – `innerHTML`.

Example:

```
handleClick: function(e) {
  alert(e.currentTarget.innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image: This worked for me]
You can  use `innerText` , `innerHtml` or `textContent`