# How to access text data between tags in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to access text data between tags in React.

For example:

```
<select>
  <option>none1</option>
  <option>none2</option>
</select>
```

How do I access `none1` and `none2` using `e.target`??

I tried to access those using `e.target`...
But, I don't know what to write after `e.target`.

Comment: e.target.innerHTML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React - Get text of div on click without refs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36414432/react-get-text-of-div-on-click-without-refs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using plain JavaScript

```
let opt = document.getElementsByTagName('option');
opt[0].textContent; // This will access 'none1'
opt[1].textContent; // This will access 'none2'
```

Here

```
variable opt is of type NodeList,
opt can be looped for getting all the textContent for tags.
```

From `e.target`

```
e.target.textContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

As from the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html), you could set the options value with the same text

```
<select>
  <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
  <option value="lime">Lime</option>
  <option selected value="coconut">Coconut</option>
  <option value="mango">Mango</option>
</select>
```

And then you could grab it with `e.target.value`