# getting value from Material UI pagination

Tags: reactjs, pagination, material-ui

I need to get the number of the selected page so I can show the user certain data.
I've got this pagination element:

```
<Pagination count={5} variant="outlined" shape="rounded" onChange={handlePagination} />
```

And it looks like this:
[image: Pagination]

So I added onChange action with function "handlepagination" which looks like this:

```
function handlePagination (event) {
console.log(event.currentTarget)
}
```

And when I for example click button number 4, I get this output:
[image: output]

Can anybody help me get the number of the page, in this case, the "4" string? I tried event.currentTarget.value but that does not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can access it this way.

```
console.log(event.target.textContent)
//or
console.log(event.currentTarget.textContent)
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36414432/react-get-text-of-div-on-click-without-refs/50894853#50894853) are other solutions.

Answer (score 7):

You can use second parameter returned by the `onChange` event on the Pagination component(React Material) to get the current page number like below

```
onChange={(event, pageNumber) => pageChangeHandler(event, pageNumber)}


pageChangeHandler(event, pageNumber = 1) {
    // Your code 
}
```